Qlik Sankey chart to display only non null value for a dimension
I am trying to display a sankey chart with multiple dimensions, among which one of the dimensions has NULL values as well, but i do not want them to be visible.
If i try to hide the null values on that dimension it gets resized and not having the same scale as the other dimensions.
This is the actual output at the moment.

What i want to achieve is display the dimension SRS with 560, hide the NULL values of the SRS dimension, but not to resize it. I want to keep a common scale for all dimensions from left to right.
